# Better way to represent this list?

Tags: formatting, lists

I am writing a paper about Cantor's set and in the following excerpt I have a list of four items. Each item has a short description which is directly to the right.

I really don't like the way that itemize looks, specifically that it is so far to the left and not centered. Does anyone know a good way to format a list like this? I am open to any and all suggestions.

```
To begin, consider the points in $[0,1]$ represented in ternary. By removing the open middle third from $[0,1]$, we remove all numbers of the form $0.1\textnormal{xxxx}..._3$ where the $0.0\textnormal{xxxx}..._3$ is strictly between $0.0000..._3$ and $0.02222..._3$. The ``strictly" conditions ensures that $0.1_3$ and $0.1222..._3 = 0.2_3$, are not removed. Thus, the numbers remaining in $[0,1]$ after the first removal have the form


    \begin{itemize}
        \item $0.0\textnormal{xxxx}..._3$ \hspace{5mm} Numbers between $0$ and $1/3$
        \item $0.02222..._3$ \hspace{5mm} $1/3$
        \item $0.12222..._3$ \hspace {5mm} $2/3$
        \item $0.2\textnormal{xxxx}..._3$ \hspace{5mm} Numbers between $2/3$ and $1$
    \end{itemize}
```

Comment: What are the "..." parts supposed to signify? A typographic ellipsis? If so, it would be better to write `\dots`.

Comment: I also think you should write `0.0\overline{22}_3` (=`0.1_3`) and `0.1\overline{22}_3` (=`0.2_3`) to denote more clearly that the digit `2` is repeated indefinitely. Otherwise, somebody might misread `0.02222..._3`, say, as containing `0.02222111100002222..._3` as a valid element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of list is probalbly better use `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
To begin, consider the points in $[0,1]$ represented in ternary. By removing the open middle third from $[0,1]$, we remove all numbers of the form $0.1\textnormal{xxxx}..._3$ where the $0.0\textnormal{xxxx}..._3$ is strictly between $0.0000..._3$ and $0.02222..._3$. The ``strictly" conditions ensures that $0.1_3$ and $0.1222..._3 = 0.2_3$, are not removed. Thus, the numbers remaining in $[0,1]$ after the first removal have the form
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{\textbullet}c >{$}l<{$} l}
    &   0.0\text{xxxx}\dots_3   &   Numbers between $0$ and $1/3$   \\
    &   0.02222\dots_3          &   $1/3$                           \\
    &   0.12222\dots_3          &   $2/3$                           \\
    &   0.2\text{xxxx}\dots_3   &   Numbers between $2/3$ and $1$
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
or beter without bullets?
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} l}
0.0\text{xxxx}\dots_3   &   Numbers between $0$ and $1/3$   \\
0.02222\dots_3          &   $1/3$                           \\
0.12222\dots_3          &   $2/3$                           \\
0.2\text{xxxx}\dots_3   &   Numbers between $2/3$ and $1$
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]